# Tableau Creating Segment

Tags: tableau-api

I'm new here and hope you guys could help.
I'm trying to to split the users by "Desktop Only", "Smartphone Only", and "Desktop & Smartphone" users.

As you can see the data, a user can have multiple devices:

[image: screenshot]

I would like to segment the users into 3 types of user as mentioned above

Answer (score 0):

Create 3 formulas:

1. For Desktop

   `if device_type = "Desktop"
   then database field .users
   end`

Similarly create for other 2 options aswell

Comment: Thanks Siva!  Sorry,what I meant to do is based on the above, I would like to create a new field so for example user#7 will show as "Smartphone & Desktop", while  User#1 will be "Desktop Only" and User#2 as "Smartphone". I'm trying to avoid pivoting the data because it has over 8 million rows.